# RegEx to implement resources in asp.net pages through visual studio search-replace

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, visual-studio-2010

I'm currently going through our asp.net pages to implement globalization.

However the task of adding globalization to the asp text is boring and error-prone. This can be obviously automated! The kind of replacement I wanna do is as follows:

From:

```
<asp:Label ID="whatever" runat="server" Text="This is the text" />
```

To:

```
<asp:Label ID="whatever" runat="server"
    Text="<%$Resources:ResourceName, This is the text%>" />
```

Tags finishing with `Text`, `Message`, `Title` or `ToolTip` should be replaced. For example:

```
<asp:Control ID="whatever" runat="server" HeaderText="Header"
    ErrorMessage="You did it wrong">
```

Should become:

```
<asp:Control ID="whatever" runat="server"
    HeaderText="<%$Resources:ResourceName, Header%>"
    ErrorMessage="<%$Resources:ResourceName, You did it wrong%>">
```

One exception is that **empty text should not be globalized**.

I want to use the Visual Studio search-replace function with regex.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it myself..

Find what:

```
{Text|Message|ToolTip|Title}="{[^<"]+}"
```

Replace with:

```
\1="<%$Resources:ResourceName, \2%>"
```